# Using a hyphen (-) in the DOI field in Kile for Bibiliography

Tags: bibtex, doi

I am trying to write my thesis in Latex. While adding bibiliography, I noticed that if there is a hyphen (-) in the DOI field, I cannot compile. PDFLaTeX command after BibTeX does not show error, but gets frozen and no PDF is generated. I tried Biber instead of BibTeX but did not work. If I remove the hyphen, it gets compiled and the Bibiliography gets displayed correctly in the PDF. How do I include the hyphen?

Hyphens in other entries like Author name, page number etc are working without doing any manipulation.

This is my bib entry

```
@article{2010-Yu,
author  = {Xing Yu and Tae-Young Lee},
journal = {Tellus A: Dynamic Meteorology and Oceanography},
number  = {5},
pages   = {617-632},
title   = {Role of convective parameterization in simulations of a convection band at grey-zone resolutions},
volume  = {62},
year    = {2010},
doi     = {10.1111/j.1600-0870.2010.00470.x}

}
```

10.1111/j.1600-0870.2010.00470.x this is the problem entry. If I remove the hyphen in 1600-0870, the PDF gets generated.

I saw many entries stating problem with underscore, but I have no issues with underscore, only with hyphen in the DOI.

The bib style I am using is agu08.bst

I am using Kile version 2.9.91 on Ubuntu 18.04

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You should really post a compilable example (I do not have your bst style, for example). Anyway, have you tried to load `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` in your preamble? For the example, see [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was trying to include a MWE, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Also, yes I used that but it didn't work. I resorted to using bibitem in the main tex page and put the hyphen there and it worked. Slightly tedious roundabout way but I am pressed for time so I will have to be okay with it.

Comment: I will close this question for now, and in the future, I will try my best to include a MWE. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: No need to close it, maybe somebody will pick it up someday. When you have time, add the example by editing it...